# Create Wordpress users with LDAP backend

Tags: wordpress

I'm setting up a Wordpress site that I need to get and store user info in LDAP. I have found a few plugins that will let me auth my users against LDAP and that is a start. What I need is new user registration to create the users in LDAP and password resets to update the passwords in LDAP as well.

The LDAP server is running OpenLDAP and [LAM](https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/) is installed, I know that there pro version does user provisioning but it doesn't let me redirect the people back to my WP install after they have created an account.

Ideally I would like to find a plugin for WP that would solve this but if I had to redirect users to my LDAP server for account creation that would be ok if at the end of the process I could send them back to the URL they came from.

---